# Error while importing demo content for a wordpress theme "Your server don't have permission read widgets setting file. Widgets setting isn't imported"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, wamp

I am trying to import demo content for a wordpress theme. But I am getting following errors while doing that and content is not getting uploaded at all.

1) Your server don't have permission read widgets setting file. Widgets setting isn't imported

2) Your server don't have permission read options file. Theme options isn't imported

Please guide me through this. I am doing it in wamp server local host.

Comment: I think you are importing data from your theme options?

Comment: Yes, I am importing data from theme options